# Multiple -replace issue

Tags: powershell

```
$FichierModifié = $Modele -replace "< NOM_ECOLE >" $_.NOM_ECOLE -replace "< ADDR_FW_LAN >", $_.ADDR_FW_LAN -replace "< ADDR_POOL_DHCP_LAN >", $_.ADDR_POOL_DHCP_LAN -replace "< ADDR_FW_WAN >", $_.ADDR_FW_WAN -replace "< ADDR_MASK_WAN >", $_.ADDR_MASK_WAN -replace "< ADDR_GW_WAN >", $_.ADDR_GW_WAN -replace "< MAC_FW >", $_.MAC_FW -replace "< PPPOE_USERNAME >", $_.PPPOE_USERNAME -replace "< PPPOE_PASSWORD >", $_.PPPOE_PASSWORD
```

I want to make this line more readable. I tried a lot of solutions that I found here but nothing is working for me.

```
$Modele.Replace("<NOM_ECOLE>", $_.NOM_ECOLE).
Replace("<ADDR_FW_LAN>", $_.ADDR_FW_LAN).
```

The code above gives me an error like

> "." is an invalid token

same with `` ` `` instead of the `.`.

Comment: The target string cannot be empty (e.g. `replace("", $_.ADDR_FW_LAN)`).  What are you hoping that this will do?

Comment: I modified my post, sorry about that, this is my first post be kind with me ahah

Comment: The easiest way to make it more readable is to add whitespace.  Put each `-replace "foo","bar"` on its own line with a backtick at the end of each line to signal PS it should all be parsed as one line.  If you want to go further, put the substitutions in an array and replace in a loop.

Comment: Thank you it worked !, just a simple backtick at the end of each line no need of parenthesis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to make it more readable is to add whitespace. Put each `-replace "foo","bar"` on its own line.  You will need a backtick at the end of each to tell PowerShell that it should all be parsed as one line.

```
$FichierModifié = $Modele `
  -replace "< NOM_ECOLE >" $_.NOM_ECOLE `
  -replace "< ADDR_FW_LAN >", $_.ADDR_FW_LAN `
  -replace "< ADDR_POOL_DHCP_LAN >", $_.ADDR_POOL_DHCP_LAN `
  -replace "< ADDR_FW_WAN >", $_.ADDR_FW_WAN `
  -replace "< ADDR_MASK_WAN >", $_.ADDR_MASK_WAN `
  -replace "< ADDR_GW_WAN >", $_.ADDR_GW_WAN `
  -replace "< MAC_FW >", $_.MAC_FW `
  -replace "< PPPOE_USERNAME >", $_.PPPOE_USERNAME `
  -replace "< PPPOE_PASSWORD >", $_.PPPOE_PASSWORD
```

If you want to go further, put the substitutions in an array and replace in a loop.  This is most useful if you're making similar replacements in many places.

```
$replacements = @(
  @{src="< NOM_ECOLE >"; target = $_.NOM_ECOLE}
  @{src="< ADDR_FW_LAN >"; target = $_.ADDR_FW_LAN}
  @{src="< ADDR_POOL_DHCP_LAN >"; target = $_.ADDR_POOL_DHCP_LAN}
  @{src="< ADDR_FW_WAN >"; target = $_.ADDR_FW_WAN}
  @{src="< ADDR_MASK_WAN >"; target = $_.ADDR_MASK_WAN}
  @{src="< ADDR_GW_WAN >"; target = $_.ADDR_GW_WAN}
  @{src="< MAC_FW >"; target = $_.MAC_FW}
  @{src="< PPPOE_USERNAME >"; target = $_.PPPOE_USERNAME}
  @{src="< PPPOE_PASSWORD >"; target = $_.PPPOE_PASSWORD}
)

$FichierModifié = $Modele
foreach ($x in $replacements) {
    $FichierModifié = $FichierModifié -replace $x.src, $x.target
}
```

Comment: +1 on adding an alternative but beware that performance wise, it  adds a lot of overhead. On a personal note: I find the cascading `-replace` version more readable. It takes one look to know what it does whereas the foreach loop takes +one looks ;)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Agreed.  I would only use the second form if I needed the same set of replacements in several places, so to not violate DRY.